# How can I create a combobox with a list of countries in a React app and manage the data by caching it from a database using the Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I'm developing a React application, and I'd like to add a combobox to the registration page where users can select their countries. Since the list of countries is static, I'm aiming to create some sort of cache mechanism to efficiently handle the data instead of fetching it from the database every time. Additionally, I'm using the Context API for state management in my application.

I currently have two main questions:

How can I display the list of static country data within a combobox? I'm thinking of sourcing this data from a resource like a JSON file rather than hardcoding it. I'd like to understand the steps I need to follow.

How can I cache the country data fetched from the database, so I don't have to access the database again every time the page reloads? How can I manage this data using the Context API?

Any help, suggestions, or sample code snippets regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I put loading until the page is loaded, get the data and then assign the default value, but instead of constantly requesting, I think it would be more logical to save it in the cache and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.